# How do you decrypt ASPXAuth, what is the IV?

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, encryption, .aspxauth

Does anybody know what Key and IV are used to encrypt/decrypt the ASPXAUTH cookie? 
I think I have the Key part figured out.

After extensive reading and research (and other questions posted here) I see ASPXAUTH uses the FormsAuthentication.Encrypt and Decrypt methods. They in turn use whatever algorithm and keys you have defined in your machineKey section in your web/machine.config files.

As a refrence I've read these articles:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16822/The-Anatomy-of-Forms-Authentication

If I used the following machineKey (from an msdn example on deploying in a server farm):

```
  <machineKey
    validationKey="32E35872597989D14CC1D5D9F5B1E94238D0EE32CF10AA2D2059533DF6035F4F"
    decryptionKey="B179091DBB2389B996A526DE8BCD7ACFDBCAB04EF1D085481C61496F693DF5F4"
    decryption="AES"
/>
```

Accorting to the later link, ASPXAUTH will use AES (implemented as RijndaelManaged in managed code) with the above settings.

I would like to try to decrypt using a standard RijndaelManaged function, but the input requires a Key and IV.

I am assuming I can use the decryptionKey for the key if I convert it from Hex to a byte array, easy enough.

However what do I use as the input for the IV? I can't find this information or setting anywhere.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but many times the IV is either pre-pended to the message (the IV always being one block) or a zero'd out block is used as the IV. You could try both options and see if you get output that makes sense. Simply try to decrypt with a zero IV, if only the first block is incorrect and the rest is a correct message then that is the IV..

Comment: Tried that this morning; this doesn't seem to work.  Hopefully someone else knows where the IV is created from.

Comment: Are you certain that AES does not mean AES/ECB ? In that case there would not be an IV.

Comment: not entirely certain, but the second link above states: encrypted using AES (implemented as RijndaelManaged in managed code)

Comment: That does not exclude a specific encryption mode in any way. CBC with a random IV is the default, but ECB without IV can be configured just as well (and a few other modes).

Comment: I think I found something, so just to clarify more information in case someone else searches and finds this link... it is hard coded to use a Random IV value every time

Comment: That would be the default mode for AESManaged and RijndaelManaged encryption in .NET. However, I would expect a higher end function to manage such things automatically.